# faster loading of like buttons

Tags: google-plus, facebook-like

I am using the following code to load the facebook, g+, twitter buttons faster.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(doc, script) {
    var js, 
        fjs = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0],
        frag = doc.createDocumentFragment(),
        add = function(url, id) {
            if (doc.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = doc.createElement(script);
            js.src = url;
            js.async = true;
            id && (js.id = id);
            frag.appendChild( js );
        };
    // Google+ button
    add('http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js');
    // Facebook SDK
    add('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxx', 'facebook-jssdk');
    // Twitter SDK
    add('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(frag, fjs);
  }(document, 'script'));
</script>
```

I put the above code at the end of the HTML.
In my testing, the above code seems to be loading the buttons faster than keeping them individually.

Is there is anything else that can be be added to above code to make the buttons load faster than above?

Thanks

Comment: Consider experimenting with dns prefetching.  Try adding <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//apis.google.com"/> to your <head>

Comment: +1 for teaching me the ways of `createDocumentFragment`, I haven't met with this DOM function so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use https in Google+ URL, at the time of writting this putting `https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js` instead of `http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js` will get rid of one roundtrip.

It's possible that same goes for other two services as well but I haven't tested because I use custom buttons.